# IP64 PCB connectors to avoid wirings

Tags: connector, enclosure, ip67

To minimize the costs for wiring an electronic enclosure, often designers put connectors at the edge of the PCB, that fit in slots made on the enclosure walls. The most common example is a mini PC:

[image]

To have an idea, in my application I need IP64 connectors with the following specifications:

- 2 pins: 24V 10A
- 4 pins: 2x 24V 10A + 2x signals
- 8 pins: signals

I went through the most common manufacturer catalogs but I didn't find a connector family that could fit my needs. Usually, most IP64 connectors are not available for PCB mounting because they are intended to be mounted on a front panel and then wired to the PCB.

Is there a solution for this request? Or I just need to stick with panel connectors and internal wirings?

Comment: I think I've seen M8/M12, PCB mount, IP6X connectors.

Comment: @WesleyLee, I was looking for them. Would you mind to share some product code?

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a solution for this request? Or I just need to stick with panel connectors and internal wirings?

I am aware of a partial solution. There are products available that combine the enclosure and sealed connectors. Your board is soldered to the part of the enclosure with the connectors, then the full enclosure is assembled to make a sealed whole.

Obvious limitations are the enclosure sizes available and the high cost.

[image: Cinch LE Automotive Enclosure]

[Example IP67 Product Link](https://belfuse.com/product-detail/modice-modice-modular-connector-enclosures-shs-harness-connectors)

Answer (score 2):

If your target is IP64, you can't avoid to use a panel mounted connector. The problem is that those connectors require an O-ring which needs to be pressed against the panel thanks to a nut to guarantee a high IP level, as illustrated below (female socket on the right) :

[image: LEMO connector]

[Image link](https://www.lemo.com/en/products/low-voltage-connector/k-connector)

If this connector was mounted on a PCB, well, you will face some difficulties to attach it on the panel because it will not be able to go through the hole where it should be screwed (the socket is larger than the hole).
With the mini PC of your picture, there is not this issue because the panel holes actually don't hold the connectors so they can be PCB mounted which indeed costs less money.

Comment: Got it. I hoped the connector could be inserted from inside (with the oring) and the nut from the outside.

Comment: Some connectors can be assembled like that, @Mark, maybe something from Fischer works that way and is sealed but I haven't used them in years, and probably not PCB. Assembly would otherwise be problematic for PCB mounting as the socket would have to be inserted through the panel, done up, and then soldered. The hole position tolerance is also tighter than with unsealed connectors, and the holes smaller.  Not completely impossible, but there's not going to be much demand.

Answer (score 2):

A search on Digikey for **"Panel Mount, Through Hole, Right Angle"** connectors with IP64 or better protection does give some results.
For example [TE T4145 series](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/T4145415021-001/7649179) or [Switchcraft EN3P8 series](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/switchcraft-inc/EN3P8MRAPCBN/3880538).

They have only 4 A current rating, but you could parallel multiple pins to achieve the 10 A.